# Como hacer que un metodo en angular espere hasta que se ejecute la funcion find

Tags: angular, typescript, angular10

tengo un metodo en angular al cual le paso el numero de contrato, sin embargo inicialmente hay una lista de contratos ya precargada en la cual debo encontrar el contrato que entra al metodo dentro de la lista que tengo en memoria de la siguiente forma:

```
async abrirContrato(contrato){
let areaUsuariaNombre = await this.data.find(element => element.Id == contrato.numContrato);
   
this.creacontrato.areaUsuariaNombre = String(areaUsuariaNombre.Nombre);  }
```

Al tratar de asignar el resultado a la variable AreaUsuario nombre me arroja error de que no el campo es indefinido ya que como la secuencia la hace tan rapido termina antes de que la funcion find termine, hay alguna solucion para esto por favor.

Comment: Si los datos guardados en `this.data` están en memoria ni siquiera es necesario el await. Si el error es `undefined` significa que lo que se busca no se encontró.

Comment: vale entiendo lo del await, sin embargo la lista de this.data tienen muchos registros y si existe el parametro que estoy buscando solo que cuando pasa a asignar la variable como es tan rapido aun no ha encontrado el dato, si le hago debug el me muestra que en efecto encuentra el registro pero si lo dejo correr de una como es tan rapido el proceso no le da tiempo de buscar el dato cuando ya esta asignando la variable es por eso que me arroja undefined, por que aun no ha terminado de buscar y ya esta asignando la variable que aun no ha sido cargada

Comment: Si `data` es una lista de elementos en memoria no importa que tenga 100M de elementos, el código se ejecutará de forma secuencial y hasta que termine de buscar pasará a la siguiente instrucción.